# r - sf::st_within output is sparse geometry binary predicament format. How to convert to character or logical vector

Tags: r, vector, geometry, sf, within

The same question is asked here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49294933/r-convert-output-from-sfst-within-to-vector
but I thought this might be a more suitable place for GIS related questions.

Im trying to use the sf package in R to see if sf object is within another sf object with the `st_within` function. My issue is with the output of this function which is sparse geometry binary predicate - `sgbp` and I need a vector as an output so that I can use the `dplyr` package afterwards for filtering. Here is a simplified example:

```
# object 1: I will test if it is inside object 2
df <- data.frame(lon = c(2.5, 3, 3.5), lat = c(2.5, 3, 3.5), var = 1) %>% 
st_as_sf(coords = c("lon", "lat"), dim = "XY") %>% st_set_crs(4326) %>%
  summarise(var = sum(var), do_union = F) %>% st_cast("LINESTRING")

# object 2: I will test if it contains object 1
box <- data.frame(lon = c(2, 4, 4, 2, 2), lat = c(2, 2, 4, 4,2), var = 1) %>%
  st_as_sf(coords = c("lon", "lat"), dim = "XY") %>% st_set_crs(4326) %>% 
  summarise(var = sum(var), do_union = F) %>% st_cast("POLYGON")

# test 1
df$indicator <- st_within(df$geometry, box$geometry) # gives geometric binary predicate on pairs of sf sets which cannot be used 
df <- df %>% filter(indicator == 1)
```

This gives  Error: Column `indicator` must be a 1d atomic vector or a list.

I tried solving this problem below:

```
# test 2
df$indicator <- st_within(df$geometry, box$geometry, sparse = F) %>% 
  diag() # gives matrix that I convert with diag() into vector
df <- df %>% filter(indicator == FALSE)
```

This works, it removes the row that contains TRUE values but the process of making a matrix is very slow for my calculations since my real data contains many observations. Is there a way to make the output of `st_within` a character vector, or maybe a way to convert `sgbp` to a character vector compatible with `dplyr` without making a matrix?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is how you can get a logical vector from sparse geometry binary predicate:

```
df$indicator <- st_within(df, box) %>% lengths > 0
```

or to subset without creating a new variable:

```
df <- df[st_within(df, box) %>% lengths > 0,]
```

I cannot test on your large dataset unfortunately but please let me know if it is faster than matrix approach.